# How to deal with missing data when there actually is no value but 0 is not an option?

Tags: feature-extraction

I am in the data preparation phase of my data mining project and about to handle missing values. My dataset contains information about purchase transactions of an e-commerce company, among others the order and delivery date.

I constructed a variable named deliverytime out of these 2 variables, but there are several missing values in delivery_date and hence also in deliverytime. If there is a missing value in derliverydate, it actually means that the product has never been shipped. Now I do want to account for that, but assigning the value 0 for deliverytime for those observations is not feasible, cause there is the option of express shipment where products are acutally deliverd on the same day. I also do not want to assign a value like "999" cause then I can only treat this variable as a factor.

Does anyone have ideas how to deal with this problem? Would you consider creating a new variable named "delivered" that takes the value of 0 if it has never been delivered and 1 if yes?

Greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: This depends a lot on your language. Some will have an "optional" type or template that can be used for things that may be set. If you are using a database SQL implementations have optional columns. This as it is is too broad. You at least need to choose a language to do this in...

Comment: This is what NULL was meant for. Whether you have null'able types at your disposal depends on your platform, of course.

Comment: The language I am using is R. I am not sure if assigning NULL is feasible cause the data will be used for neural networks, decision trees and logistic regression?